# Subsetting output in R to generate summaries

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

The following is a dataframe(DF) with a set of  marketing campaigns I conducted. Success percentage shows the number of respondents, and communication type refers to the channel- facebook, twitter etc(Ai- FB, L1-Linkedin).  Laptop, New  and mouse refer to the words that make up the sentence. The original dataframe had a sentence- say Buy a new laptop and get a mouse free. I have parsed the above with qdap and generated DF below.

```
 Sl NO  Success_Percentage  communication_type  Laptop  New    Mouse
   1    35.46666667             email              1      0      0
   2    32.32830821             email              1      0      1
   3    22.9226361              SMS                0      1      0

   4    21.88888889             SMS                1      1      0
   5    40.04085802             FB                 0      1      1
   6    38.7283237              FB                 1      0      1
```

I have sorted out DF based on the communication type . The values under the three words that make up the sentence indicate whether the same were present in the original sentence sent during the communication.

The most frequent keywords across all communications are given by the following code

```
   Wordlist2<-as.data.frame(colSums(DF)[colSums(DF)>0])
```

the output for Wordlist2 is as follows

```
    Laptop  4
    New     3
    Mouse   3
```

I want to know how to obtain the above output subsetted by communication type. It can be done manually but I would like to know if any package exists that can do this.

```
 require(dplyr)
  DF%>%
     group_by(communication_type, Success_Percentage)%>%
     summarise(colSums(DF))
```

But that is not working.

Comment: Are you sure you want to group by `Success_Percentage` ? It's a continuous value, and unique in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure it's what you want, but in any case I'm pretty sure you want `summarise_at`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="Sl_NO  Success_Percentage  communication_type  Laptop  New    Mouse
   1    35.46666667             email              1      0      0
   2    32.32830821             email              1      0      1
   3    22.9226361              SMS                0      1      0
   4    21.88888889             SMS                1      1      0
   5    40.04085802             FB                 0      1      1
   6    38.7283237              FB                 1      0      1",stringsAsFactors=F,header=T)

require(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(communication_type) %>% summarise_at(c("Laptop","New","Mouse"),sum)

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   communication_type Laptop   New Mouse
#                <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1              email      2     0     1
# 2                 FB      1     1     2
# 3                SMS      1     2     0
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed to subset the columns but it has worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `dplyr`, but I have a solution for `data.table`:

```
#---Input data
DF <- read.table(text = "Sl_NO  Success_Percentage  communication_type  Laptop  New    Mouse
                       1    35.46666667             email              1      0      0
                       2    32.32830821             email              1      0      1
                       3    22.9226361              SMS                0      1      0
                       4    21.88888889             SMS                1      1      0
                       5    40.04085802             FB                 0      1      1
                       6    38.7283237              FB                 1      0      1", header = T)

DF <- as.data.table(DF) #---Convert DF from data.frame to data.table

DF[, .N, by = communication_type]
```

Produces:

```
   communication_type N
1:              email 2
2:                SMS 2
3:                 FB 2
```

edit:

```
DF[, .(Laptop = sum(Laptop), New = sum(New), Mouse = sum(Mouse)), by = communication_type]
```

Produces:

```
   communication_type Laptop New Mouse
1:              email      2   0     1
2:                SMS      1   2     0
3:                 FB      1   1     2
```

Comment: Neat. Its simple.